# How to change the output of a command if it has been called already?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I want to create a command that changes its output the second time it gets called. For example, I want it to yield 1 the first time it's called, and 2 the second time:

```
\newcommand\mycommand { do stuff }
\mycommand % yields 1
\mycommand % yields 2
```

My idea was to define a global variable, something like `\hasbeencalled`, and globally redefine that variable if the command has been called. Something like:

```
\def\hasbeencalled{0}
\newcommand\mycommand[1] {
    \ifnum\hasbeencalled=0
        1
        \global\def\hasbeencalled{1}
    \else
         2
    \fi
}
```

But this doesn't work. Somehow the global redefinition happens retroactively and changes it so that I get the output

```
\mycommand % yields 2
\mycommand % yields 2
```

But if I take away the `\global`, then I get

```
\mycommand % yields 1
\mycommand % yields 1
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

as plain tex but works in latex as well:

```
\def\mycommand{1\gdef\mycommand{2}}

\mycommand

\mycommand

\mycommand

\bye
```

Comment: `\bye` in LaTeX?

Comment: @cfr as it says in what I wrote, the example is plain tex, but the definition would work in latex.

Comment: All I meant was that somebody who doesn't know much about TeX/LaTeX is likely to copy paste all of the code and not realise they should just use the relevant bit. But maybe I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 5):

You can just set a "toggle", which starts out as being false, and is set to true once you've received the special input.

Below I've made an `\if` that represents this toggle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@mycommand@special
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{7}=0 % Compare argument to "7" (or something special)
    \if@mycommand@special
      #1 (subsequent call)%
    \else
      #1 (first call)%
    \fi
    \global\@mycommand@specialtrue% "7" has been used...
  \else
    #1% Do something else
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\mycommand{1}

\mycommand{2}

\mycommand{1}

\mycommand{7}

\mycommand{9}

\mycommand{7}

\mycommand{9}

\mycommand{7}

\end{document}
```

Comparison is done using e-TeX's `\pdfstrcmp{<strA>}{<strB>}`, which performs a string comparison. The result is 0 if the `<strA>` = `<strB>`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I don't know why, but this isn't working where I'm applying it. I'm trying to use it inside of a tikz plot, and I get "subsequent call" all times :\

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron: The usage of this *within* some other context surely makes for a complication. Could you please add these details to your question so we can replicate your problem?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron If you mean pgfplots by TikZ yes it won't work. You have to expand the macro immeadiately before the axis environment is finished.

Comment: @percusse how can I do that?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron: Please show us a use-case.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a simple typing error. In your `\ifnum` you use `\hasbeenseen` but everywhere else it's `\hasbeencalled`. If you change it you get a working

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\hasbeencalled{0}
\newcommand\mycommand[1] {
    \ifnum\hasbeencalled=0
        1
        \global\def\hasbeencalled{1}
    \else
         2
    \fi
}

\mycommand{}
\mycommand{}

\end{document}
```

Please note that you define `\mycommand` with an mandatory argument (which you don't use) so you should call it

```
\mycommand{}
\mycommand{}
```

giving empty arguments. A simple

```
\mycommand
\mycommand
```

will result in plugging the second `\mycommand` as argument for the first one and thus only showing one number.

Comment: And you get so many spaces… `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: I suspected, Werner had only presented us a reduced version and his real-world use actually uses this argument, so I didn't change the definition.

Comment: I think @egreg means the *other* spaces, but I could be mistaken.