# Possible to change command output after first use?

Tags: macros

I am wondering if it is possible to change the output of a `\newcommand` after it is used once? I am creating a template for video transcription and I want the names to appear in full once, and then just the first letter in subsequent lines.

I would like to do the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{NameOfPerson: #1} % what do I change here?
\begin{document}

\mycommand{Transcription of what the person says here}
\mycommand{Another line from the same person}

\end{document}
```

And the output to look something like:

NameOfPerson: Transcription of what the person says here

N: Another line from the same person

---

I am new to LaTeX so please forgive me if this is a simple question!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  I took the liberty to remove the greetings and the signature from your question, as the style guidelines of this site prescribe. :-)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to change the output of a command if it has been called already?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287545/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t need anything special:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\mycommand}[1]{N.:\nobreak\space ##1}%
    NameOfPerson: #1%
}



\begin{document}

% \show\mycommand

\mycommand{Transcription of what the person says here}

% \show\mycommand

\mycommand{Another line from the same person}

\mycommand{Yet another line from the same person}

\end{document}
```